# How to Store multiple id/passwords using a master key

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, security, encryption

similar to say FireFox which allows a master key to store various id/passwords

We would need to store multiple user id/passwords to multiple databases and password protected documents rather than having the user enter those every time they use the app ( wpf )

Not quite sure where to start, hoping there's a library that provides this feature ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do it like this:

1. For each user create a [certificate, with symmetric key](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1312/managing-sql-server-2005-master-keys-for-encryption/) being his password.
2. When the user authenticates, decrypt the username/password pair values stored for him in the database using his password.
3. Keep the username/password in memory using [SecureString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.securestring.aspx)
4. Use it when you want.